# React js actions not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react js and tried a small piece of code

```
import  * as template_actions from '../actions/actions'
class EmailTemplateList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.template_actions.add_template({'name': 'Ramesh'}))
        return (<div>
            Welcome
        </div>);
    }

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        template_actions: bindActionCreators(template_actions, dispatch)
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EmailTemplateList)
```

actions.js

```
export const ADD_EMAIL_TEMPLATE     = 'ADD_EMAIL_TEMPLATE';
export function add_template(payload){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            payload: payload,
            type: ADD_EMAIL_TEMPLATE
        });
    }
}
```

But the error is

```
Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions
```

Could not find the solution.

Comment: put the code where you have called your action

Comment: I have updated code and called action in render method

Comment: you should use redux-thunk or redux-promise to handle async action

Comment: I am not clear which action is async here.

Comment: you may need a Redux middleware https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware

Comment: Thanks all, I fixed it using redux middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using redux-thunk middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        payload: payload,
        type: ADD_EMAIL_TEMPLATE
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import  * as template_actions from '../actions/actions'
class EmailTemplateList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.add_template({'name': 'Ramesh'}))
        return (<div>
            Welcome
        </div>);
    }

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        add_template: payload => dispatch(template_actions.add_template(payload))
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EmailTemplateList)
```

actions

```
export const ADD_EMAIL_TEMPLATE     = 'ADD_EMAIL_TEMPLATE';
export function add_template(payload){
    return ({
            payload: payload,
            type: ADD_EMAIL_TEMPLATE
        })
}
```